# collect data from table views swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have made an app where so far, the user enters subjects, and a table view comes up with the name of each subject, along with its own slider and slider value label. See below:

[Click Here for Image (I don't have enough reputation yet to embed an image.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xi7jr.png)

I want to be able to collect and process the data for each subject and the value of the slider, as well as the total value of all the sliders combined.

I am not sure how to go about this. I have tried the code below to get the total of all the sliders, but it doesn't work, and I am not sure how to attempt it from here.:

```
class SubjectsViewControllerTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

var isSliderTotal: Float = Float(GlobalSubjects.subjects.count) * 50
var lastUp: Float = 50
var lastDown: Float = 50
@IBOutlet var subjectLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var percentLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var slider: UISlider!
@IBAction func slider(_ sender: Any) {
    (sender as AnyObject).setValue(Float(roundf(slider.value * 1) / 1), animated: true)
    print("test")
    let sliderValueAsVar = String(slider.value)
    percentLabel.text = String(sliderValueAsVar.components(separatedBy: ".")[0])
    if slider.value > 50 {

        let currentSlider = slider.value - lastDown
        lastDown = slider.value
        isSliderTotal += currentSlider
        print (isSliderTotal)

    }
    else if slider.value < 50 {

        let currentSlider = slider.value + lastUp
        lastUp = slider.value
        isSliderTotal -= currentSlider
        print (isSliderTotal)

        }
    }
    override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

I also do not know have a clue about how I would get the value of each slider and subject, except from the fact that you might use a dictionary?

Any help would be hugely appreciated :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need a **model** in the view controller which maintains the values of the sliders and a callback closure in `cellForRow...` which is called when the slider value changes to update the model and do the math you need.

Answer (score 0):

you can use delegate.
In your tableViewController:

```
protocol YourTableViewCellDelegate {
    func passSliderValue()
}

class YourTableViewController: UITableViewController, YourTableViewCellDelegate {
     override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let currentCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "YourCellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! YourTableViewCell
        currentCell.delegate = self
    }

    func passSliderValue(){
    //deal with your data
    }
}
```

In yourTableViewCell.swift
add the property:

```
var delegate: YourTableViewCellDelegate!
```

and then in your func slider(_ sender: Any) , calling:

```
self.delegate.passSliderValue()
```

when you need pass the value of slider